# How to set different colors for different options in a select with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to generate a 'select' with a different color for each 'option' with jQuery.

I did that:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="taxonomy" name="taxonomy"></select>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#taxonomy').append($('<option></option>').val('-ANY-').html('-- ANY --'));
    $('#taxonomy').append($('<option></option>').val('Critical').html('Critical'));
    $('#taxonomy').append($('<option></option>').val('Warning').html('Warning'));

    $('#taxonomy option[value="Critical"]').css('color', 'red');
    $('#taxonomy option[value="Warning"]').css('color', 'orange');
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, it's only working on Firefox. There is no color in Chrome or Safari...

Do you have better solution working on any browser ?

Thanks.

Comment: [I see color](http://jsfiddle.net/eM7Jm/)

Comment: Well it doesn't work for me on Mac OSX Lion and Google Chrome 13.0.782.215...

Comment: It doesn't work on Mac OSX with Opera 11.50 or Safari 5.1 neither...

Answer (score 1):

[works fine for me !](http://jsfiddle.net/6SgD9/1/)

using latest chrome on windows. I know there is/was a os x webkit bug for it thou.